# “Content Library” tools in iMovie

Tags: imovie

I have up loaded a `.mov` file to iMovie. However, I am unable to see the tool for “Content Library” in the bottom left of the screen

Why can't I see the “Content Library Tool” in iMovie?

Answer (score 1):

Found [this solution](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5552662?start=0&tstart=0):

> They will only show up when you define/activate a project. So the
>   timeline of a project needs to be active.
>
> To start a new project, go to File>New Movie.
>
> To edit an existing project, go to All Projects in the sidebar and
>   double-click on one of your existing projects.

Comment: That works. Thanks for your help. Too simple!